# How to install both python 2 and python 3 on windows using Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I want to install both python 2 and python 3 on My windows laptop including their kernels on Jupyter notebook. I tried the following method, it works for My macbook. However, I came across a problem on my Windows system. Here is the detailed steps.

1. download and install the latest version of installer anaconda3.exe first.
2. using command `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` to install python 2 with power shell.

with `conda info -e`, I can see the following information (the python 2 seems not under Anaconda3 for Mac OS, but it's the case for Windows)

py27                     C:\Users\account\Anaconda3\envs\py27

root                  *  C:\Users\account\Anaconda3

It goes smoothly in general, but after typing `activate py27`, it didn't return anything(should be fine). However, when I type `python`, in power shell, it turns out that it's python 3.6.1 rather than python 2.7. Additinally, I failed to set up the python 2 kernel as the following code as well:
`conda install -n py27 ipykernel
 activate py27
 python -m ipykernel install --user`
Although the return of the 1st fine is fine, the return of the last command indicated that it installs python 3 rather than python 2. What's wrong of my command, why `activate py27` doesn't work in my case, how can I fix it?

Comment: This is a known issue with Powershell, you cannot activate and deactivate environments using Powershell. See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626

Comment: @darthbith Then how can I overcome this, using another terminal instead of Power shell?

Comment: Use the regular command prompt (cmd) and activate-deactivate will work fine. Or read that GitHub issue to activate using Powershell, I should have said "by default, you cannot..."

Comment: Cool, it works, it's not convenient to use cmd in general, another good terminal you would recommend under Windows to replace Powershell?